# Use java to parse xml with several parents

Tags: java, xml

i´m new to java and parsing and have studied all simple examples. They give me the basics, but how would i parse a more advanced xml-file like the one below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<employee name="carlos">
  <employment_form works="fulltime">
     <employment_number>555</employment_number>
     <days_worked>200</days_worked>
     <employment_deps dependencies="started">
        <Another_Employee NAME="jenny"/>
        <Another_Employee NAME="jimmy"/>
     </employment_deps>
     <employment_deps dependencies="now">
        <Another_Employee NAME="jenny"/>
        <Another_Employee NAME="jimmy"/>
        <Another_Employee NAME="lisa"/>
     </employment_deps>
  </employment_form>
  <employment_form works="parttime">
     <employment_number>554</employment_number>
     <days_worked>21</days_worked>
     <employment_deps dependencies="started">
        <Another_Employee NAME="mike"/>
        <Another_Employee NAME="donny"/>
        <Another_Employee NAME="fredrik"/>
     </employment_deps>
     <employment_deps dependencies="when finished">
        <Another_Employee NAME="trish"/>
        <Another_Employee NAME="carl"/>
        <Another_Employee NAME="noone"/>
     </employment_deps>
    </employment_form>
   </employee>
```

I want to show a detailed list of each employment_form;

```
carlos fulltime 555 200 started
jenny
jimmy
carlos fulltime 555 200 now
jenny
jimmy
lisa
carlos parttime 554 21 started
mike
donny
fredrik
carlos parttime 554 21 now
trish
carl
noone
```

I hope some can help me, I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: You could read [mkyong articles](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/). They're useful guides for XML parsing for java.

Comment: If you have well-formed XML, any Java library should be able to parse it.  An XML file should only have *ONE* root element (e.g.  `employees`).  But nevertheless, your file is indeed "well formed": https://validator.w3.org/check. Here is one (of many) good tutorials: [Java and XML](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html)

Comment: U can use XStream :http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html

Comment: Yes, i started with mkyong articles, but found they lacked a little when extra nested elements came into action.
I started out with SAX, but found it easy to use, but did not have enough "power" for this problem, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could simple use java dom parser to parse your xml document.

A crude example to produce the desired result is

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class XmlParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new File("xmlfile"));
            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
            String employeeName = root.getAttribute("name");
            NodeList employmentForm = doc.getElementsByTagName("employment_form");

            for (int i = 0; i < employmentForm.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = employmentForm.item(i);
                NamedNodeMap attribute = node.getAttributes();
                String works = attribute.getNamedItem("works").getNodeValue();

                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element = (Element) node;
                    String employeeNumber = element.getElementsByTagName("employment_number").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String daysWorked = element.getElementsByTagName("days_worked").item(0).getTextContent();
                    NodeList employmentDeps = element.getElementsByTagName("employment_deps");
                    String dependencies = employmentDeps.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("dependencies").getNodeValue();

                    for (int j = 0; j < employmentDeps.getLength(); j++) {
                        output.append(employeeName).append(" ")
                              .append(works).append(" ")
                              .append(employeeNumber).append(" ")
                              .append(daysWorked).append(" ")
                              .append(dependencies).append("\n");
                        Node anotherEmployee = employmentDeps.item(j);
                        if (anotherEmployee.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element anotherEmployeeElement = (Element) anotherEmployee;
                            NodeList anotherEmployeeList = anotherEmployeeElement.getElementsByTagName("Another_Employee");
                            for (int k = 0; k < anotherEmployeeList.getLength(); k++) {
                                Node anotherEmployeeNode = anotherEmployeeList.item(k);
                                if (anotherEmployeeNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                output.append(anotherEmployeeNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("NAME").getNodeValue()).append("\n");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(output.toString());

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, excellent example! This was what i was looking for. I did already create a similiar one, which is not as good looking as yours. A edition to the code would be to store information in objects and create a array of objects. I will post my code as soon as it doesn´t look like something the dog dragged in.